# Opengl graphics code understanding

Tags: opengl

This code draws a pin on which disks are ordered ( Tower of Hanoi Pins ) in opengl . I am not understanding how this sequence of functions are gradually drawing a pin . I know primarily about the functions , their parameter lists and usage . But what I exactly want to know is the step by step output of each of them  called. here is the function :

```
void drawPin(GLUquadricObj **quadric, const GLfloat radius, const GLfloat height) 
{
    glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(-90.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        gluCylinder(*quadric, radius, radius, BREITE/2, SLICES, LOOPS);
        gluQuadricOrientation(*quadric, GLU_INSIDE);
        gluDisk(*quadric, 0.0, radius, SLICES, LOOPS);
        gluQuadricOrientation(*quadric, GLU_OUTSIDE);
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, BREITE/2);
        gluDisk(*quadric, 0.0, radius, SLICES, LOOPS);
gluCylinder(*quadric, STANGENBREITE, STANGENBREITE, height, INNERSLICES, LOOPS);
        glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, height);
        gluDisk(*quadric, 0.0, STANGENBREITE, INNERSLICES, LOOPS);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function only draws primitives with given parameters. All parameters change outside function.